# Current measurements - shunt switching

Tags: current, measurement, switching, shunt

I have been designing a current measuring device, and since it requires high wide-range accuracy, I decided to use two shunt resistors of different sizes. The schematic is shown below:

[image]

The design uses the big (2 Ohm) shunt resistor for tiny currents, and when higher currents are detected, switches the MUX and the bypassing switch (to reduce power loss) and uses the smaller resistor.

All the component names are presented in the picture, however, I enclose them here in a form of the hyperlink [Switch](https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ds31858-50268.pdf) ,  [MUX](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a2053.pdf) ,  [ADC](https://www.mouser.tw/datasheet/2/268/microchip_technology_mchp-s-a0006919354-1-1749951.pdf)   ,  [Amplifier](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina281-q1.pdf).

While testing, I encountered a problem. When switched to the 2 Ohm resistor, the behavior is as expected. However, when I switch to the small resistor, no matter how big the current is, all I get is a couple of millivolts (actually seems like the amplifier offset). Am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you measure a few millivolts? At the amplifiers output?

Comment: Are you reading the high-current voltage at the amp, or are you looking at the ADC output? If the latter, the MUX may be bad.

Comment: I am reading it right at the amplifier.

Comment: How much current?

Comment: If you are referring to how much current am I trying to detect, I tried almost 1A, which should result in 0.005*1*200 = 1V at the amplifier output

Comment: What is the resistance of the switch? i.e. what is the voltage over the switch? The ON resistance of the switch is higher than your low shunt resistor, so this will not work as you expect. There will not be 0.005*1 V at the input of the amplifier.

Comment: @TomášHavel From the last paragraph it seems you are aware that the input voltage offset worst case will represent a good amount of uncertainty in the current measurement with the smaller shunt (although this is not the reason for such low measurement at 1A). What are your accuracy requirements for each range? What is the acceptable voltage drop in your load due to the shunts?

Comment: @LukeHappyValley What do you mean? It is a differential amplifier, isn't it? The resistance of the switch should not play any role, or?

Comment: @devnull I am not looking for anything reallllyyy specific, I just really want to get this design to work. So a different design (although probably possible) isn't an option for me.. Even if this design was 'semi-accurate' it does not make sense to me, why the measurements are so low, practically zero...

Comment: Just to check off the obvious, are you sure you got the input polarity correct on the top amplifier?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany Indeed, I checked that many times.